# Output different while using debugger versus build&run C++

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, random

I'm trying to make a basic grid based dungeon crawler. When I build&run and the program prints out the board[7][10] char array only one space on the board has a 'T' character. But if I go step by step with the debugger it works perfectly and places 3 'T' characters on the board like I want it to. I have no idea how to fix this problem or what is even causing it. I'm getting no errors from the compiler, it's just strange output:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DungeonBoard.h"
#include "Tokens.h"


int main()
{
    DungeonBoard dungeonCrawl; // create DungeonBoard object
    dungeonCrawl.start(); // call start function
}
```

DungeonBoard.h

```
#ifndef DUNGEONBOARD_H
#define DUNGEONBOARD_H

class DungeonBoard
{
    public:
        DungeonBoard(){} // default constructor
        void start(); //gameplay
        void printBoard(); // print out the gameboard
    private:

};

#endif // DUNGEONBOARD_H
```

DungeonBoard.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DungeonBoard.h"
#include "Tokens.h"

const int ROW = 7;
const int COLUMN = 10;
char board[ROW][COLUMN]= {{'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}, {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
{'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}, {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
{'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}, {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}, {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}};
bool occupied[ROW][COLUMN] = {{false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
{false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}, {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
{false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}, {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
{false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}, {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}};

Tokens hero(0, 0); //creates user starting location at top left corner
Tokens treasure(6, 9); // creates treasure location at bottom left corner
Tokens trap1, trap2, trap3;

void DungeonBoard::start(){
    char userDirection; // user input
    bool gameOn = true; // sentinel value for while loop

    std::cout << "DUNGEON CRAWL 1.0\n";
    std::cout << "------------------\n\n";
    std::cout << "H is the hero, T are traps, X is the treasure and .'s are open spaces.\n";
    std::cout << "The goal is to move around the gameboard and reach the treasure while avoiding \ndtraps.\n\n";
    std::cout << "CONTROLS: W - UP, S - DOWN, A - LEFT, D - RIGHT.\n\n";
    std::cout << "Enjoy! :)\n\n";

    board[hero.get_row()][hero.get_col()] = 'H'; // set user starting position
    occupied[hero.get_row()][hero.get_col()] = true; // make space used
    board[treasure.get_row()][treasure.get_col()] = 'X'; // set treasure position
    occupied[treasure.get_row()][treasure.get_col()] = true; // make space used

    trap1.trap_loc(); // randomize location of trap 1
    while(occupied[trap1.get_row()][trap1.get_col()] == true){ //check to make sure space is not occupied
        trap1.trap_loc(); //if occupied, re-randomize
    }
    trap2.trap_loc(); //randomize location of trap 2
    while(occupied[trap2.get_row()][trap2.get_col()] == true){ //occupy check
        trap2.trap_loc(); // re-randomize
    }
    trap3.trap_loc(); //randomize location of trap 3
    while(occupied[trap3.get_row()][trap3.get_col()] == true){ //occupy check
        trap3.trap_loc(); //re-randomize
    }

    //set board spaces for traps to T and mark that space as used

    board[trap1.get_row()][trap1.get_col()] = 'T';
    occupied[trap1.get_row()][trap1.get_col()] = true;
    board[trap2.get_row()][trap2.get_col()] = 'T';
    occupied[trap2.get_row()][trap2.get_col()] = true;
    board[trap3.get_row()][trap3.get_col()] = 'T';
    occupied[trap3.get_row()][trap3.get_col()] = true;

    printBoard();
}

void DungeonBoard::printBoard(){
    for(int i = 0; i<7; i++){
        for(int r = 0; r<10; r++){
            if(r == 0)
                std::cout << "  ";
            std::cout << board[i][r] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Tokens.h

```
#ifndef TOKENS_H
#define TOKENS_H


class Tokens
{
    public:
        Tokens(){} //default constructor
        Tokens(int row, int col); //constructor with coordinates already known
        void set_pos(int new_row, int new_col){ rowLoc = new_row; colLoc = new_col;} // set new row and col values
        int get_row(){return rowLoc;} //row getter
        int get_col(){return colLoc;} //col getter
        void trap_loc(); // randomize trap location
        int rand0toN1(int n); //psuedo random number generator
    private:
        int rowLoc, colLoc; //tokens location by row and column
};

#endif // TOKENS_H
```

Tokens.cpp

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Tokens.h"
#include "DungeonBoard.h"

Tokens::Tokens(int row, int col){ //sets the position of the token
    set_pos(row, col);
}


void Tokens::trap_loc(){ //gets random row and col for trap
    int trapRow = rand0toN1(6);
    int trapCol = rand0toN1(9);
    set_pos(trapRow, trapCol); // sets position of trap token to the random numbers created
}

int Tokens::rand0toN1(int n){ //psuedo-random num generator
    srand(time(NULL)); // set seed for randomization
    return rand()%n;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Valgrind? That behavior can be a lot of things... My guess is some uninitialized variable...

Comment: You probably want to used a fixed seed until you figure this out, so that you get the same results every time.

Comment: I tried using a fixed seed as well and all that happens is the one 'T' that prints out is always in the same spot ;P

Comment: Do you know there are less verbose ways to initialize `char board[][]` and `bool occupied[][]`?

Comment: Yes, I could run them both through for loops, but I was going to do that later as I just wanted to ensure I had everything correct. Thank you though!

Comment: Actually you could do `bool occupied[ROW][COLUMN] = {};` and that would be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you keep re-initialising `srand` with the same seed when you use it inside `Tokens::rand0toN1`.  This is because `time(NULL)` has seconds resolution.

By stepping through the code, you're causing `srand` to be initialised with different values, hence the expected result.

`srand` doesn't need be called before *every* use of `rand`, it is only needed to initialise it, so if you move `srand(time(NULL));` to somewhere like the start of `DungeonBoard::start()` (basically ensure it's called once before the first use of `rand`), your program should work as expected.

Comment: I knew there was something strange about that! My father told me to put it there and I was suspicious. Thank you for clearing that up!